# phpmyadmn data connection to localhost or external server

Tags: connection, localhost

I don't know how I can do this. 
I test my web app (php+mysql) in localhost and at the same time I test in Internet too. But I change the connection data everytime I change the test.

¿Can I to know when open the web app in internet or localhost?

Data connection are the same in both cases:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "myuser";
$password = "mypassword";
$database = "mydatabase";
```

Answer (score 0):

This helps you.
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

When you use localhost then your host is "localhost", your user is "root", left blank your password if you not set any password when you install phpmyadmin and put your database name which one you create in phpmyadmin.

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "Your_Database_Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it. But in my case, external and local connection have the same data except password. I want identify if I doing a local test or internet test to change de password.